# Nested IIfs in reporting services

Tags: sql-server-2008, service

can anyone help please.  I need to put an IIf within an IIf within an IIf.  I have a parameter called 'Period' with 4 labels, '24 Hrs, 3 Days, 7 Days, Month'.  I have another Parameter ('Date' and hidden) containing the following DateSerial

```
'=DateSerial( Datepart("YYYY",Now()),Datepart("m",Now()),Datepart("d",Now())-1 )'
```

which the parameter Period defaults to on opening e.g. 20/10/2009 07:00

The third Parameter ('Date From' also hidden) is where I want to put the nested IIfs.  I want it to read from the Parameter 'Period' and depending on the selection will depend on outcome, my code so far looks like this (not completed yet as I want to see if the first two IIfs work:

```
'IIf(Parameters!Period.Value = 1, DateAdd("h", 7, Parameters!Date.Value),
 IIf(Parameters!Period.Value = 2, DateAdd("h", -41, Parameters!Date.Value)))
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

Regards, Althea

Answer (score 0):

You need a "else" value in the second IIf just in case your Period is neither 1 nor 2:

```
=IIf(Parameters!Period.Value = 1, 
    DateAdd("h", 7, Parameters!Date.Value),  
    IIf(Parameters!Period.Value = 2,
        DateAdd("h", -41, Parameters!Date.Value),
        Parameters!Date.Value)) ' If period is neither 1 nor 2 just return the date
```